# Cloud Firestore in Firebase - Get all root level collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get all the collections from root level?

---

As I know that Cloud Firestore Console allow to add more than one collection on root level.

I found [some solution to get documents of particular collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?authuser=2) but I didn't get to know same thing for collections.

Is there any way to get all collection name of root level?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in the Firebase SDKs for iterating collections.  Similarly, there is no API for iterating subcollections of a document.  You must know the name of a collection ahead of time to use it on the client.

If you're using the Admin SDK for Node, which wraps the [Google Cloud Firestore SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/), there is an API [Firestore.getCollections()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.9.x/Firestore#getCollections) that will do what you want.